# How is a reset with two shifts reified in Scala?

Tags: scala, exception, continuations

I understand from this [blog post](http://suereth.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-you-should-think-about-delimited.html) how a single `shift` within a `reset` is reified.

```
reset { 1 + shift {k:Int => Int => k(5)} + 1}
```

is reified to

```
val reified = {shiftValue:Int => 1 + shiftValue + 1}; reified (5)
```

Now I have another example:

```
reset { 
  1 + shift(k1:Int => Int => k1(5)} + 1;
  2 + shift(k2:Int => Int => k2(6)} + 2
}
```

It is reified to:

```
val reified ={shifyValue1:Int =>
    1 + shiftValue + 1; 
    2 + shift(k2:Int => Int => k2(6)} + 2
}
reified(5)
```

How can I reify it further to get rid of the 2nd `shift`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val reified ={shiftValue1:Int =>
    1 + shiftValue + 1; 
    val reified2 = {shiftValue2: Int => 2 + shiftValue + 2};
    reified2(6)
}
reified(5)
```

Basically the same transformation.

(scala not installed here, so I only tested this transformation in Scheme, which should behave the same, ignoring any type system issues.)